# How can I make this snippet prettier/better/less lines?

Tags: iphone, code-snippets

I've been trying to minimize all my functions in my app but can't really find how to make this function better, maybe someone is a lot better at this than me? :)

```
-(void)showRivBoxWithAnimtation:(BOOL)yesno {
    if(yesno) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
        if ([self alpha] > 0) { 
            [self setAlpha:0.0];
            [appDelegate.JSONparser setDelegate:self.delegate]; //Give back the JSONparser to the parent!
        } else {
            [self setAlpha:1.0];
        }
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(clearRivBoxContent:finished:context:)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } else {
        if ([self alpha] > 0) { 
            [self setAlpha:0.0];
            [appDelegate.JSONparser setDelegate:self.delegate]; //Give back the JSONparser to the parent!
        } else {
            [self setAlpha:1.0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
-(void)showRivBoxWithAnimtation:(BOOL)yesno {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:yesno ? 0.2 : 0.0
                     animations:^{
        if ([self alpha] > 0) { 
            [self setAlpha:0.0];
            [appDelegate.JSONparser setDelegate:self.delegate]; //Give back the JSONparser to the parent!
        } else {
            [self setAlpha:1.0];
        }
        }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
        if (finished) {
            // Do the stuff from clearRivBoxContent:finished:context:
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: That is way better than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the order of operations wrt. alpha is critical; this is probably the smallest it can be made.

```
-(void)showRivBoxWithAnimtation:(BOOL)yesno {
  if ([self alpha] > 0) { 
    [self setAlpha:0.0];
    [appDelegate.JSONparser setDelegate:self.delegate]; //Give back the JSONparser to the parent!
  } else {
    [self setAlpha:1.0];
  }

  if(yesno) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(clearRivBoxContent:finished:context:)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
  }
}
```